# Map OneToMany side as the owner

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm having hard time understanding the following piece of [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)
what does the comment

> We need to duplicate the physical

means ?

What's the point of using insertable=false, updatable=false ?
Please, Can you help ?

> To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the
>   owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many
>   to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false. This solution
>   is not optimized and will produce some additional UPDATE statements.

```
@Entity

public class Troop {

    @OneToMany

    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information

    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {

    ...

}


@Entity

public class Soldier {

    @ManyToOne

    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)

    public Troop getTroop() {

    ...

}
```

Comment: Is `troop_fk` referenced in another `@Column` on the `Soldier` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We need to duplicate the physical

It's mean that Hibernate will link to column `troop_fk` in `Soldier` entity to connect with `Troop` entity. And we must write physical name of column that connecting `Troop` and `Soldier`.

> What's the point of using insertable=false, updatable=false ?

Because it's foreign key to `Troop` entity and you can't edit it, because of constraint. First you create `Troop` and after that you add `Soldier` in this `Troop`.

This example about `OneToMany` map when owning side is `OneToMany` side, so this side own relationship and we assume that this side created first. You can delete `insertable=false, updatable=false` but if you have constraint in your DB and try to create `Soldier` with new `Troop` object you can get constraint violation error, because of this new `Troop` entity does not exists in `Troop` table.

Comment: what if we don't use these annotations:insertable=false, updatable=false ?

Comment: @GionJh add to answer